# Natural Language Processing for an optimal solution to Hangman

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I have a dictionary of 250,000 words and am supposed to design an algorithm to play the game of Hangman as follows:

1. We are given a random word, not necessarily from the dictionary.
2. We have N attempts to guess the correct word by guessing each letter individually. Each incorrect guess leads to a penalty leading to losing an attempt.
3. Unlimited correct guesses are allowed.
4. The game stops when we either make N incorrect guesses or we have guessed the correct word.

A common algorithm I came across is as follows:

1. The algorithm starts with a masked string, replacing some letters with underscores.
2. It searches a dictionary to find all possible words matching the pattern. (The length of the word, say)
3. Then, it analyzes the frequency of letters appearing in these potential words and creates a table to keep track of these frequencies.
4. Next, it selects the letter with the highest frequency among the remaining unguessed letters as the best guess.

I understood the algorithm given above. However, my question is, if I get a random word, ***not necessarily from the dictionary of words***, won't this algorithm fail to work? What is a more efficient method to tackle this broader problem?

Comment: Your algorithm sounds good. Just try to get a larger dictionary that includes all words you can be given.

Comment: You could use your incomplete dictionary to calculate probabilities of n-grams (e.g. 3-grams) to find the most likely character to ask next.

Comment: @Stef That would be a more brute-force method, in my opinion. Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Could you elaborate a bit more? I am not well versed with the concept of n-grams, apologies for the same.

Comment: @Anweshsaha A 3-gram is just a sequence of 3 characters inside a word. If your hangman can contain "made up words" that are not in your dictionary, then you should still expect words like "Natpropisol" to be more likely than words like "Wkjrptlmnx", because every sequence of 3 adjacent letters in "natpropisol" looks like it could come from real English words, whereas the sequences of 3 adjacent letters in wkjrptlmnx are all super unusual.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I would still advocate using the dictionary to look for the next character, and then letter frequency as a fallback if the dictionary runs out.